# NDC coordinates to Camera Coordinates

Tags: three.js

I have a scenario in which the mouse is over the screen and I want to calculate the 3d coordinate the mouse represents in the XY- plaine of the camera. 
The nice way would be to convert NDC mouse coordinates that I have to the matching camera coordinate with which I struggle. Alternatively I could create a fake mesh at the given distance and just use a raycaster - but that seems really ugly.

Since I struggled I tried looking up how three.js raycaster calculates 3d coordinates from ndc coordinates and found the matching lines for PerspectiveCamera

```
this.ray.origin.setFromMatrixPosition( camera.matrixWorld );
this.ray.direction.set( coords.x, coords.y, 0.5 ).unproject( camera ).sub( this.ray.origin ).normalize();
```

That doesn't make much sense to me since the ray origin should depend on the mouse coordinates as well and not just the camera. In comparison the ray direction I would only expect to depend on the camera but not on the coordinates.

I guess I am thinking to much in terms of orthogonal coordinate systems and not in terms of a perspective camera, but I can't make any sense of it. IF sb has a good reference for camera perspectives that'd be great too. Cheers Tom

Comment: Hi how did you setting the mouse?

Comment: @headmax: Not exaclty sure what you mean. I listen to a mouse event and convert standard JS mouse coordinates to NDC coordinates for the three.js area of the screen. That works well as many raycasting ops I do work.

Comment: i mean the code : but we see 2 lines of raycaster and the rest is magical :), i am no aware of you NDC word i dunno what you mean?

Comment: As an option, instead of a fake mesh, you can create an instance of `THREE.Plane()` and find the point of intersection with the ray of your raycaster.